# Python 2.7 and 3.4: Libraries inaccessible across versions

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, compatibility

I am new to Python. I am running Ubuntu 14.04, and I have both Python 2.7 and 3.4 on it.

I want to use the newer 3.x version, with the NumPy, SciPy, and NLTK libraries. I set the Python REPL path to Python 3.x in the ~/.bash_aliases file like so:

> alias python=python3

After this I installed several libs, including python-numpy, python-scipy, and python-matplotlib.

> $ sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose

Unfortunately, I am facing issues since I am guessing that the libraries got installed for the older 2.7 version of Python; I am unable to access the libraries using the 3.4 REPL.

> import numpy
>
> > ImportError: No module named 'numpy'

However, I am able to access the libraries using the older version:

> $ /usr/bin/python2.7

How do I get this this work?

Comment: You need separate installs for each python version.  Python 3 now has decent support, so you probably just do, eg, `sudo apt-get install python3-numpy` (although I haven't tested)

Comment: Oh. Is that a convention, that the newer libs for v.3.x will be suffixed with 3 at the end of python? Like this: python3-numpy python3-scipy python3-matplotlib. Sorry if this sounds newbie-ish; I am new to Python.

Comment: @sapi, had missed adding your name in the comment :)

Comment: When you use `apt-get`, you're installing libraries from your distribution package manager (ie Ubuntu for you).  They use the `python3-` convention.  You could also use `sudo pip3 install numpy` to install using Python's package manager, but that can be a bit fiddly with dependencies.  If you're new, I'd stick to the former.

Comment: Hey, thanks @sapi. Really appreciate your answer. Can you actually make it a proper answer to the question so that I can mark it as such? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install Python packages using `apt-get`, you're relying on the distribution package manager.  The Ubuntu convention is to prefix Python 2 packages with `python-`, and Python 3 packages with `python3-`.

This distinction is necessary because Python 3 introduced some incompatible changes from Python 2.  It's thus not possible to simply recompile (most) packages for Python 3, meaning both need to be made available.

Alternatively, you can use the Python package manager, `pip` (or `pip3`).  The catch with this is that some packages (like `scipy`) require certain compiler toolchains which you might not have installed.

It's generally a good idea to stick to either `apt-get` or `pip` for a particular machine.  You *probably* won't have issues if you mix them, but it's better to be consistent.